# What is the center of Earth's landmass?

Tags: mass, earth

I have read, several times, that the Great Pyramid is located at "the center of Earth's landmass".

How do we define "Earth's landmass"? And once defined, how do we find the center of it?

Comment: The wikipedia article provided by the accepted answer states: "it is the superficial barycenter of the mass distribution produced by treating each continent or island as a region of a thin shell of uniform density and approximating the geoid with a sphere." The first words in the barycenter article are "In **physics**". Also in the first mentioned article:  "Andrew J. Woods, a **physicist** with Gulf Energy & Environmental Systems in San Diego, used a digital global map and calculated the coordinates". Perhaps someone could tell me what it is, rather than repeating "it is not about Physics".

Comment: if that's meant to be an argument that the question is about physics, it's a _remarkably_ weak one; in any case, this is probably a geology question.

Comment: @DavidZ From the beginning, I was not sure if this was an appropriate place to ask this question. I'm trying to come to a conclusion based on what has been given to me. However, continuing the stream of thought, it seems that if how we find the center of Earth's land mass is satellite dependent, then surely quite a bit of physics is involved. Launching the satellite and maintaining a proper orientation would have to be included in how we find the center.

Comment: I noticed that someone added http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/what-is-centroid-of-all-lands-of-earth at the bottom of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_centre_of_Earth). I was not aware of gis.stackexchange before this.

Answer (score 2):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_centre_of_Earth) has a quick discussion and finds the center to be near Ankara, Turkey.  I would think a better point would be well inside the earth, the CM of the thin shell discussed in the article.  Finding an average point on the surface of a sphere(oid) is problematic.  It depends on your definition.

Comment: There is no magic about where you split the Mercator projection.  You can split it anywhere you want, then determine the centroid of the land that is shown.  If you show the whole earth, the centroid would be down in Antartica-there is infinite area down there.

Comment: Based on recent developments I have decided I won't accept an answer to this question unless it describes the full process of determining the center. You retain my upvote! ;-]